# How to stretch div and input elements inside of jQuery dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have prepared [a simple jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afarber/cmgk0d83/) for my question:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see in the screenshot above there is a yellow `div` element representing chat area and underneath it there is text input for entering chat messages.

Please help me with my problem -

How to "stretch" the `chatDiv` and `chatInput` elements, so that they occupy maximal amount of space in the dialog?

As you can see in the screenshot, there is currently lot of padding around those elements, especially around the text input element (because I don't know, how adjust its width besides setting the `size` attribute).

Obviously I am looking for a most portable solution, working for any (or most) browsers and font sizes.

Here is my code -

```js
function sendChat() {
  var str = $('#chatInput').val().trim();
  $('#chatDiv').append('<br>' + str);
  $('#chatInput').val('');

  var h = $('#chatDiv').prop('scrollHeight');
  $('#chatDiv').animate({ scrollTop: h }, 1000);
  $('#chatInput').focus();
}

$('#chatInput').on('keyup input', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    sendChat();
  }
});

$('#chatDlg').dialog({
  minWidth: 500,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    'Send': function() {
      sendChat();
    },
    'Close': function() {
      //$(this).dialog('close');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
@import url("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css");
div#chatDiv {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="chatDlg">
  <div id="chatDiv"></div>
  <p align="center">
    <input id="chatInput" type="text" size="20" />
  </p>
</div>
```

Here is my would-like-to-have image:

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: `#chatInput { width: 100%; }` and remove the `<p>` tag

Comment: Sam thank you - and what to do with the `size="20"` attribute?

Comment: yeah you can remove that, you shouldn't need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `class` attribute to the elements that need to be 100% width
Then define the CSS for that class:

```
.fullwidth {
  width: 100%;
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/cmgk0d83/6/

Answer (score 1):

A simple cross-browser way to achieve this is to use some absolute positioning inside of the dialogue box while making sure that the `#chatDiv` content doesn't go behind the input. This is done by setting a padding bottom that is equal to the height of the input:

```css
#chatDlg {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  border: solid 1px grey;
}
#chatDiv,
#chatInput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
#chatDiv {
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  padding-bottom: 30px;/* height of the chat input */
}
#chatInput {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="chatDlg">
  <div id="chatDiv"></div>
  <input id="chatInput" type="text" />
</div>
```

If cross-browser wasn't as much of an issue I'd say that this would be an ideal use-case for a flexbox column, which would remove the need to manually offset the height of the input.